# Psql pivot table with related data

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab

I'm trying to create a pivot table from related data. I am planning on using this data to better understand which tags are correlated to high frequency users.

I have a `users` table, a `tag_users` and a `tags` table.

**EDIT**
The non-pivoted query is

```
SELECT users.id, tags.title 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN tag_users ON tag_users.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN tags ON user_tags.tag_id = tags.id
```

I would like to create an output with the following format:

```
user_id | tag_1_name | tag_2_name | ...tag_{n}_name 
1         1            0            1
```

I have ~ 196 tags and ~ 40,000 users and downloading tags a a comma separated field and then doing a lookup on excel breaks my computer.

I am aware of `crosstab` but I can't find any examples where it uses related data.

What do you suggest as a suitable solution?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what in the crosstab examples you've seen, does not seem to fit? Can you show the non-pivoted query?

Comment: @DanielVérité Added the non-pivoted query in the original post